# WP Multisite + SSL gives 404 on wp-admin

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl, multisite

I have installed SSL certificate on my server via DirectAdmin. This seems to be working well.

I've changed my url's in the `wp_*_options` tables to `https://mydomain.nl` and such. Suddenly my `wp-admin` stopped working, its just redirecting from `https://mydomain.nl/wp-admin/` to `https://mydomain.nl/not_found` showing me the 404 page from my theme.

How can I debug this to find the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can [force](https://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL) admin area to SSL connection by defining following code in wp-config.php

```
 define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```